# How can I add from a CheckBoxList to a List<>?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkboxlist

I have for instance a list of 5 checkbox items:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="Listbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <CheckBox x:Name="Item1" Content="Item1" Checked="Item1_Checked"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="Item2" Content="Item2" Checked="Item2_Checked"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="Item3" Content="Item3" Checked="Item3_Checked"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="Item4" Content="Item4" Checked="Item4_Checked"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="Item5" Content="Item5" Checked="Item5_Checked"/>
    </ListBox>
```

For every checkbox that is checked, I want the item to be added to a list called myList.

So I tried this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<string> myList;

    private void Item1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myList.Add(Item1);
    }
```

Problem is, "Item1" isn't an object so it can't be added to a list of objects.

After I have some objects in my list, I want to sort them in a specific order, for example by name, and than display the list in a pre-made templates.

Any suggestions?

Hope that you understand me, my english is not perfect and I'm new to c# and wpf :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Source` property of the `RoutedEventsArgs` parameter passed to the checked handler. Also, you can use the same event handler for all checkboxes:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Listbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <CheckBox x:Name="Item1" Content="Item1" Checked="Item_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Item2" Content="Item2" Checked="Item_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Item3" Content="Item3" Checked="Item_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Item4" Content="Item4" Checked="Item_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Item5" Content="Item5" Checked="Item_Checked"/>
</ListBox>


private void Item_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myList.Add((e.Source as CheckBox).Name);
}
```

The control that initiated the event can be found in `RoutedEventArgs.Source`. You need to cast it, of course, to the control type.

In your particular case you can also use `sender`, but it's typically safer to  rely on the `Source` property.